Multiple conda environments in a single singularity container
The title is pretty much the question.
Is it possible to generate multiple conda/mamba environments in a single container using the recipe.
I've been trying using the code below but when I build the container, only the first environment is created.
%post
        mamba create --quiet --channel bioconda --name fastqc python=3.9 numpy fastqc multiqc
        mamba create --quiet --channel bioconda --channel conda-forge --name conda-env python=3.9 numpy
        conda config --add --yes channels defaults
        conda config --add --yes channels conda-forge
        conda config --add --yes channels bioconda
        conda config --set --yes channel_priority strict

This seems like a relatively simple and likely common desire but I can't find any information in my searches.
Any help would be appreciated.
The code above is what I tried.
I'm expecting this.
$ singularity shell gge_container_v3.sif
Singularity> conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /opt/mamba
fastqc                   /opt/mamba/envs/fastqc
conda-env                /opt/mamba/envs/conda-env

I'm getting this:
$ singularity shell gge_container_v3.sif
Singularity> conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /opt/mamba
fastqc                   /opt/mamba/envs/fastqc

